# Morning sickness symptoms

Tags: pregnancy

I'm pregnant for the first time, and I've never really had morning sickness until recently.  What are the normal signs and symptoms of morning sickness?  What are some signs and symptoms I should look out for that would indicate that I should call my doctor?  Are there any foods that can affect the severity of morning sickness?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! While I'm sorry to hear of your troubles, we can't safely tell what has happened here, let alone predict whether the baby will be ok (most likely, it will). There are *lots of reasons* for sickness - morning sickness, food poisoning or a mild stomach bug come to mind, but *we can't diagnose you via internet*. If you are very worried or the sickness persists, see your doctor. If you are feeling better, chances are high that everything is ok. *Usually*, there should be no need to worry about the baby, even if you had some kind of mild sickness.

Comment: I've edited this into something that can be answered, I think, and hopefully answers your ultimate question as well.  We can't diagnose your specific problem here, but we can give you some idea of what things are like.  If you're concerned about your health, call your obstetrician - that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on your pregnancy. I had bad morning sickness with both my pregnancies, that became hyperemesis with the second. Here are some suggestions of what might help you deal with it:

- eating crackers as soon as you wake up
- small meals regularly
- lots of high quality protein (this one really worked for me)
- staying hydrated, sipping lemon water or 1Tbsp apple cider vinegar in water all day
- acupressure bands
- Pregnancy of Nausea homeopathic remedy

Stay connected with your midwife or doctor. If you feel terrible and can't keep water down, you'll know to need to seek medical help. Good luck.